# Downloading a file from https works in Chrome but not C#

Tags: c#, http, download, webclient

This code used to work with a simple WebClient.DownloadFile(). But
something has happened on the server end and I can't figure out what
to do.This is my latest code. I would appreciate any available help.

The first attempt uses WebClient

```
static bool ValidateServerCertificate( object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Cert Validation");
    return (true);
}


// ** First try -- Using WebClient
static void ACNTest3()
{
    string sPostURL = @"https://www.pxw1.snb.ca/acs/rinex/2020/085/FRDN/FRDN085m.19n.Z";
    string sBasePath = @"D:\";


    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;


    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Other");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/x-compress");   // IE uses this ?  I also tried Z and zip
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    // ** SHOULD DOWNLOAD A .Z FILE, BUT ACTUALLY BOUNCES TO ERROR.HTML
    wc.DownloadFile(sPostURL, sBasePath + "third.html ");

}
```

The second way I tried was using HttpRequest/Response.   This allowed me to use cookies.  Also based on feedback, I tried to first log into the server -- which seemed to work.   But as soon as I try to get the actual file I get bounced to the same error

If I do these 2 steps in IE or Chrome, it works... but I don't know why this doesn't.   I'd appreciate any help I can get.   The code above worked for a long time, but recently the website has had server changes and this stopped working.

```
// ** Next try -- Adding cookies and a login step
static void ACNTest4()
{
    string sURL = @"https://www.pxw1.snb.ca/acs/rinex/2020/085/FRDN/";
    string sFile = "FRDN085m.19n.Z";
    string sBasePath = @"C:\";


    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    // Establish a connection with the website and get cookies
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    HttpWebResponse response = resp as HttpWebResponse;

    //** CORRECTLY DOWNLOADS THE DIRECTORY HTML -- SAME AS CHROME
    WriteStreamToFile(response.GetResponseStream(), sBasePath + "Fifth.html");


    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL + sFile);
    req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    resp = req.GetResponse();
    response = resp as HttpWebResponse;

    //** ERROR -- BOUNCES TO ERROR HTML AND DOWNLOADS THAT
    WriteStreamToFile(response.GetResponseStream(), sBasePath + "Sixth.html");
}
```

Comment: What version of C#? Is this a client app trying to access your "server"? What is the OS this code is run on?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Windows 10 Home.  VS Community 2019 v16.4.6

Comment: If I type the sPostURL string into Chrome, it downloads the proper file.   When I run this code, it downloads an error html page from the server.   The exact same URI... so there is something that Chrome is doing that this C# isn't doing.

Comment: Does the server think that .Z is an `application/zip` file? Again, need to know what kind of failure you're seeing. What is the http status code? Any other clues in the error html?

Comment: Hi Jeremy:  How do I find the http status code?   One problem I've been having is that the only feedback I get is from the error file being downloaded... and that just says that I hit the wrong page.

Comment: The request to .../FRDN/FRDN085m.19n.Z returns 302 redirect and navigates to error.html which returns 200. If you paste this URL to chrome and it works, this means that you have a persistent cookie (or already logged in to the web site on that same or another chrome browser since they do cookie sharing). It does not work on Chrome either, and returns the error.html. What you need to do is, then, to first post a login request, keep the cookies or whatever the site is using to preserve authentication between resources, and then to request this file by sending the authentication information along

Comment: Oguz:  If I am going to implement cookies and login, should I use HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse instead?

Comment: I'm stumped... I change to HttpWebRequest/Response and added in cookies and made 2 calls to the server.   The first one actually returns the exact same thing as Chrome does -- a list of the directory -- but when I actually try to get the file, it bounces to the error page.   I'll put my new code at the top below my first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The server has enforced TLS 1.2

You to use it:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    wc.DownloadFile(sPostURL, sBasePath + "third.html");
```

Comment: I added that, but it didn't help :(

Comment: But I tried your code and it failed and I added this statement and it worked. What is the exception you are getting after enabling TLS 1.2 ? Full details please

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception at all, it just downloads an error html from the server instead of the proper file.   I wonder what is different from your setup and mine that it worked for you?   Did you check the downloaded file?   It should really be a .Z file -- and when unzipped it should be a text file and the first line should be "     2.11           OBSERVATION DATA    M (MIXED)           RINEX VERSION / TYPE"

Comment: If it's the wrong file it will be html and the first line will be "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"

Comment: Ok it is an error.html, you are right. But you told that the download was working from the browser, which is not correct. You should still log-in to get this *.Z file. What you need to do is, then, to first post a login request, keep the cookies or whatever the site is using to preserve authentication between resources, and then to request this file by sending the authentication information along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I wasted people's time on this...  I had the file name wrong... it should have been 
     https://www.pxw1.snb.ca/acs/rinex/2020/085/FRDN/FRDN085m.20n.Z

not 
     https://www.pxw1.snb.ca/acs/rinex/2020/085/FRDN/FRDN085m.19n.Z

On the bright side:  I know a lot more about cookies now.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comments, please use @<username> when asking something in a comment so that the person in question does not miss it.